# prove , if $ \frac {dy}{dx} = 0 $ then $ y = c$ for some constant $c$ .

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

we all know that if $ y = c $ for some constant $c$ then , $ \frac{dy}{dx} = 0 $

but how can we prove the other way ? , i mean , how can we

prove that , if $ \frac {dy}{dx} = 0 $ then $ y = c$ for some constant $c$ .

that is not a homework . it's just a question i want to know its answer !

i hope that you take my question seriously :)

so , can anyone give us the simplest prove ?!!

thanx for all

Comment: Do you know the mean value theorem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume $f'(x) = 0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}.$

By the [Mean-Value Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem), *for any* $ x,y \in \mathbb{R} $ such that $ x < y $, we have

$$f(x) - f(y) = f'(c) (x - y)$$

where $c \in (x,y)$. Since $ f' = 0,\;$ by assumption, it follows that $ f(x) - f(y) = 0\cdot (x-y$ \implies f(x) = f(y)$.

But $ f(x) = f(y) \implies f(x) = f(y) = C$, for some constant C. That is, $f(x) = C$ is the constant function.

---

Intuitively, you can think of $dy/dx = f'(x)$ as the *slope of a line*, where $f'(x) = 0$ implies that the line is horizonal, i.e. the corresponding equation is given by $y = 0\cdot x + c \implies y = f(x) = c$, a line parallel to the x-axis and intersecting the y-axis at $c$.

Comment: [Mean-Value Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem): if a function f is continuous on the closed interval $[x, y]$, where $\,x \lt y$, and differentiable on the open interval $(x, y)$, then there exists a point $c$ in $(x, y)$ such that

    $$f'(c) = \frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x-y} \iff f(x) - f(y) = f'(c)(x - y)$$

Comment: Magic Mean-Value Theorem calls me for a plus.

Answer (score 6):

Just use the Mean-Value Theorem. For any $ x,y \in \mathbb{R} $ satisfying $ x < y $, we have
$$
f(x) - f(y) = f'(c) \cdot (x - y)
$$
for some $ c \in (x,y) $. As $ f' \equiv 0 $, it follows that $ f(x) = f(y) $.

Comment: ... and this proof should be in every calculus textbook ...

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on how you <strike>rigorously</strike> define your notion of differentiation. If you go the route Andres has suggested, you are using the *geometric* definition of differentiation.

On the other hand, the *algebraic* definition of differentiation (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_derivative for instance) <strike>takes your statement as an axiom</strike> allows your statement to be proved in a more general context.

Comment: -1: Here are two problems with this answer.  (i) What's "rigor" got to do with it?  There is a standard definition of the derivative, which comes in many equivalent forms.  The OP is surely asking about this.  (ii) In the context of derivations on polynomial rings it is not an "axiom" that the kernel consists of constant functions.  It is not even a theorem in positive characteristic: $(t^p)' = 0$, for instance.

Comment: I'm not sure it helps the discussion to bring up the case of positive characteristic, because that would probably confuse the OP. Rigor was probably not the right word, but keep in mind that what is "standard" for you might not be what is presented to a beginning calculus student.

Comment: You were the one who introduced derivatives in the ring-theoretic sense.  My remark to you was intended to drive home the point that the kernel of the polynomial derivative being the constant functions is not an axiom.  Where did you get the idea that $f' = 0$ implies $f$ is constant is an axiom in any context?

Comment: I suppose I have been too vague for your liking. The definition I had in mind is the one typically used in the context of manifolds where you are working with smooth functions defined on spaces that are locally $\mathbb{R}^n$. To be specific, I am citing the definition on page 43 of Sharpe, R.W. "Differential Geometry". Graduate Texts in Mathematics. Springer, 1997.

Comment: I have Sharpe's book and I am now looking at p. 43.  (It starts with "(i) Linearity"...) I don't see anything on this page which talks about $f' = 0$ implying $f$ being constant, axiomatically or otherwise.  Could you be more specific?

Comment: Bottom line: I was mistaken and you've enlightened me. Indeed, $$f'\equiv 0\implies f \mbox{ is constant}$$ is slightly less trivial than I expected. Prove it by using Proposition $4.10$ (page 44, "Differential Geometry") then an MVT argument for each coordinate as in Haskell Curry's answer.

Comment: In fact, the statement $$f'\equiv 0\implies f \mbox{ is constant}$$ is not well-defined in the context I am describing. The correct analogue is
$$D(f)\equiv 0, \qquad \forall D\in T(M) \implies f\mbox{ is constant}$$. This follows from Proposition $4.10$ (page 44, "Differential Geometry") then an MVT argument for each coordinate as in Haskell Curry's answer.

Comment: Thanks for your willingness to think things through and respond to my comments.

Answer (score 0):

If $f'=0$, then for every $x,y$ we have $\displaystyle f(y)=f(x)+ \int_x^yf'(t)dt=f(x)$. Therefore, $f$ is constant.